# getting an error while trying to build my program using python 3.4.2.4 (windows 7-64bit): ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4.uic.port_v2.invoke'

Tags: pyqt4, python-3.4, cx-freeze

as part of my learning curve of python, I had created a program that calculates the retirement calculator. I managed to create my first build. however I decided to enhanced my program where when user clicks on help menu : "how to.." instead of text, it will  open phonon vplayer. 
the phonon player is created with PyQt4.
the "help" player is a addition  py file that is called from the main program:
`

```
def About():
# we are loading the  video player script here (hilfe.py)

     hilfe.main()
```

`

My problem is that when I try to packaged the whole thing, my build gives me the error: "ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4.uic.port_v2.invoke' "
Why is it complaining about port_v2 when the scripts is created in python3?
Below is my setup.py :

```
`
import sys
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

path = sys.path.append(os.path.join("..", "..", "Modules"))

packages = ["tkinter","numpy","matplotlib","matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg","tkinter.filedialog","PyQt4","PyQt4.QtCore","PyQt4.phonon","sip","re","atexit"]
excludes = []
buildOptions = dict(create_shared_zip=False)

options = {"packages": packages,
           "excludes": excludes
           }
#########Preparation for target file #################
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"



file = Executable(
script ="Can_I_retire2.py", packages=["win32com.gen_py"],
base=base,
compress = True,
icon = None,
appendScriptToExe=True,
appendScriptToLibrary=False)

##########SETUP####################

setup( 
name = "Retirement Calculator",
version = "0.3",
description = "Simple retirement calculator with a graph",
options = {"build_exe": options},

#shotcutName="Fincancial Calculator",
#shortcutDir="DesktopFolder",
executables =[file])`
```

any advise  is appreciated.
thanx

Comment: Because you put `PyQt4` in packages, it tries to include everything in that, including the bits for Python 2. I think putting `PyQt4.uic` in excludes should work.

Comment: You are absolutely right. i removed the PyQt4 and voila. it was build. thank you